# What is the difference between the digital temperature sensors SHT31 and DHT11 or DHT12?

Tags: i2c, temperature-sensor

I am looking for a digital temperature sensor with I2C interface.

I found the SHT31 and the DHT12 (compatible to DHT11). Both also include humidity sensors. And I found libraries for both of them. But I did not find a comparison.

https://sea.banggood.com/GY-SHT31-D-Digital-Temperature-and-Humidity-100-RH-I2C-Sensor-Module-For-Arduino-p-1167498.html

https://sea.banggood.com/KEYES-DHT12-Digital-Temperature-and-Humidity-Sensor-Module-Compatible-DHT11-For-Arduino-p-1400920.html

**What are the (significant) differences between those sensors and libraries?**

In the moment I want to use a sensor to measure the intake air temperature of a motorcycle. One degree celsius accuracy is good enough for this purpose. I don't want to calibrate them, this is why I looked for the digital sensors.

Comment: If the dht12 is as terrible inaccurate as the dht11, then the humidity is not 5% accurate, but more like 50%. The dht12 can be used for 3.3 and 5v arduino boards. The sht31-d can also be used for 3.3 van 5v arduio boards. the sht31-d is accurate. Conclusion: dht12 = bad, sht31-d = good.

Comment: Thanks, that good enough for me. I will order the SHT31-D. But for the record: Is that your personal experience or do you have any source for this information?

Comment: Both. I have a dht11 and dht22 that are very bad in measuring the humidity value. It turns out that when they are packaged in the wrong plastic, the humidity sensing element gets disturbed. This is a test (the sht31-d was not tested): http://www.kandrsmith.org/RJS/Misc/Hygrometers/calib_many.html but this test does include the sht31: https://www.kandrsmith.org/RJS/Misc/Hygrometers/calib_many_addsht31.html I also trust the information that adafruit gives: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2857